# Swift code. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When I run my app I get an error message that says

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image]
[image]

**MealViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MealViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: UIBarButtonItem!

   /*
    This value is either passed by `MealTableViewController` in `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)`
    or constructed as part of adding a new meal.
*/

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if saveButton === sender {

        let weightInt: Int? = Int(weightInKilos.text!)
        let dehydrationInt: Int? = Int(percentOfDehydration.text!)
        let lossesInt: Int? = Int(ongoingLosses.text!)
        let factorInt: Int? = Int(Factor.text!)

        let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
        let wt = weightInt!
        let dn = dehydrationInt!
        let ol = lossesInt!
        let fr = factorInt!

        // Set the meal to be passed to MealListTableViewController after the unwind segue.


        meal = Meal(name: name, wt: wt, dn: dn, ol: ol, fr: fr)

    }

   if calcButton === sender {

    if weightInKilos.text == "" && percentOfDehydration.text == "" && ongoingLosses.text == "" && Factor.text == "" {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Fields were left empty.", message:
            "You left some fields blank! Please make sure that all fields are filled in before tapping 'Calculate'.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    else {
        let DestViewController: ftrViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! ftrViewController

        let weightInt: Int? = Int(weightInKilos.text!)
        let dehydrationInt: Int? = Int(percentOfDehydration.text!)
        let lossesInt: Int? = Int(ongoingLosses.text!)
        let factorInt: Int? = Int(Factor.text!)

        let lrs24Int = (30 * weightInt! + 70) * factorInt! + weightInt! * dehydrationInt! * 10 + lossesInt!

        let lrsPerHourint = lrs24Int / 24

        DestViewController.lrsHr = "\(lrsPerHourint)"
        DestViewController.lrs24Hrs = "\(lrs24Int)"

    }

    }
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true

}

var meal: Meal?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
    nameTextField.delegate = self

    // Set up views if editing an existing Meal.
    if let meal = meal {
        navigationItem.title = meal.name
        nameTextField.text   = meal.name

        var weightInt: Int? = Int(weightInKilos.text!)
        var dehydrationInt: Int? = Int(percentOfDehydration.text!)
        var lossesInt: Int? = Int(ongoingLosses.text!)
        var factorInt: Int? = Int(Factor.text!)

        weightInt = meal.wt
        dehydrationInt = meal.dn
        lossesInt = meal.ol
        factorInt = meal.fr


        weightInKilos.delegate = self
        percentOfDehydration.delegate = self
        ongoingLosses.delegate = self
        Factor.delegate = self

        calcButton.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
        resetbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 4;

              }

    // Enable the Save button only if the text field has a valid Meal name.
    checkValidMealName()
}

// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate


func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    checkValidMealName()
    navigationItem.title = textField.text
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    // Disable the Save button while editing.
    saveButton.enabled = false
}

func checkValidMealName() {
    // Disable the Save button if the text field is empty.
    let text = nameTextField.text ?? ""
    saveButton.enabled = !text.isEmpty
}

// MARK: Navigation

@IBAction func cancel(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Depending on style of presentation (modal or push presentation), this view controller needs to be dismissed in two different ways.
    let isPresentingInAddMealMode = presentingViewController is UINavigationController

    if isPresentingInAddMealMode {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        navigationController!.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}


// Calculation outlets & actions
@IBOutlet weak var resetbutton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var calcButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var weightInKilos: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var percentOfDehydration: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var ongoingLosses: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Factor: UITextField!

@IBAction func resetButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if weightInKilos.text == "" && percentOfDehydration.text == "" && ongoingLosses.text == "" && Factor.text == "" {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "...", message:
        "There is no information to reset. Nice try though!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else {
        weightInKilos.text=""
        percentOfDehydration.text=""
        ongoingLosses.text=""
        Factor.text=""
    }
}




 }


 class ftrViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var lrs24hours: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lrsPerHour: UILabel!


var lrs24Hrs = String()
var lrsHr = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    lrs24hours.text = lrs24Hrs
    lrsPerHour.text = lrsHr

}

}
```

**Meal.swift**
    import UIKit

```
class Meal: NSObject, NSCoding {
// MARK: Properties

var name: String
var wt: Int
var dn: Int
var ol: Int
var fr: Int


// MARK: Archiving Paths

static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("meals")

// MARK: Types

struct PropertyKey {
    static let nameKey = "name"
    static let wtKey = "weight"
    static let dnKey = "dehydration"
    static let olKey = "ongoinglosses"
    static let frKey = "factor"

}

// MARK: Initialization

init?(name: String, wt: Int, dn: Int, ol: Int, fr: Int) {
    // Initialize stored properties.
    self.name = name
    self.wt = wt
    self.dn = dn
    self.ol = ol
    self.fr = fr

    super.init()

    // Initialization should fail if there is no name or if the rating is negative.
    if name.isEmpty {
        return nil
    }
}

// MARK: NSCoding

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: PropertyKey.nameKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(wt, forKey: PropertyKey.wtKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(dn, forKey: PropertyKey.dnKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(ol, forKey: PropertyKey.olKey)
    aCoder.encodeObject(fr, forKey: PropertyKey.frKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.nameKey) as! String
    let wt = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.wtKey) as! Int
    let dn = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.dnKey) as! Int
    let ol = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.olKey) as! Int
    let fr = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.frKey) as! Int

    // Must call designated initializer.
    self.init(name: name, wt: wt, dn: dn, ol: ol, fr: fr)!
}

}
```

**MealTableViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MealTableViewController: UITableViewController {
// MARK: Properties

var meals = [Meal]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller.
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()

    // Load any saved meals, otherwise load sample data.
    if let savedMeals = loadMeals() {
        meals += savedMeals
    } else {

    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return meals.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MealTableViewCell

    // Fetches the appropriate meal for the data source layout.
    let meal = meals[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name   

    return cell
}

// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}


// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        meals.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        saveMeals()
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}


/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/


// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "ShowDetail" {
        let mealDetailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! MealViewController

        // Get the cell that generated this segue.
        if let selectedMealCell = sender as? MealTableViewCell {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(selectedMealCell)!
            let selectedMeal = meals[indexPath.row]
            mealDetailViewController.meal = selectedMeal
        }
    }
    else if segue.identifier == "AddItem" {
        print("Adding new meal.")
    }
}


@IBAction func unwindToMealList(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.sourceViewController as? MealViewController, meal = sourceViewController.meal {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing meal.
            meals[selectedIndexPath.row] = meal
            tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([selectedIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
        } else {
            // Add a new meal.
            let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: meals.count, inSection: 0)
            meals.append(meal)
            tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        }
        // Save the meals.
        saveMeals()
    }
}

// MARK: NSCoding

func saveMeals() {
    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(meals, toFile: Meal.ArchiveURL.path!)
    if !isSuccessfulSave {
        print("Failed to save meals...")
    }
}

func loadMeals() -> [Meal]? {
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(Meal.ArchiveURL.path!) as! [Meal]
}
```

}

**MealTableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MealTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
// MARK: Properties

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: Provide more details about error.

Comment: Let me try to figure out how to describe it...

Comment: Hint : When ever you get this type of error add exception break point.... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html

Comment: When the code crashes, XCode will point to the line in which the unexpectedly found nil error occurred as well as the thread on which it crashed. Could you tell us where it was?

Comment: Anbu start @ the beginning and add breakpoints throughout your code, you will soon find out where it is encountering the error. The error is almost certainly a variable it has come across that has no value set.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 might be a good place to start. You shouldn't have to guess where or why your app crashed and its going to be very hard to help you locate the problem until you can identify that much.

Comment: I added some images. Do they help? There is one more picture I wanted to add, but it doesn't let me.

Comment: why not use  let wt = aDecoder. decodeIntForKey(PropertyKey.wtKey) as! Int  rather than decodeObjectForKey

Comment: I tried that, but now for `self.init(name: name, wt: wt, dn: dn, ol: ol, fr: fr)!` it says `Cannot convert value of type Int32 to expected argument type Int`. Is there something else I have to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this `convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` method

```
convenience required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    if let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.nameKey) as? String,
        wt = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.wtKey) as? Int,
        dn = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.dnKey) as? Int,
        ol = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.olKey) as? Int,
        fr = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.frKey) as? Int {
        // Must call designated initializer.
        self.init(name: name, wt: wt, dn: dn, ol: ol, fr: fr)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I put in your code, and it works awesome!